# how to update model field data when Javascript event occurs

Tags: javascript, django

I'm doing on a Django Project.
There is a post model, and the post has 'likes' field. When a user clicks the Like button on a post, I want to increase the number of the Likes of the post.

I want to solve the problem only with Django without REST framework(DRF)

what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make an endpoint that javascript can be directed to. Create a view that will do the process:

```
def add_like(request, post_id):
    # here you can create process that will find Post object by provided id
    return JSONResponse(...)  # however not needed, you can create some response with status 201
```

Then obviously url pointing to that view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('add_like/<int:post_id>', my_app.add_like),
]
```

Then anytime you will post to i.e. `/add_like/1`, it will activate the process in `add_like` view. You can put there more variables (like user who is liking).